# move (motion or visual selection) to own line and indent

Tags: indentation, plugin-vimtex, movement

Suppose I have the following text

```
\[
    X = (a, b)
\]
```

I want to easily convert it to the following, including indentation:

```
\[
    X = (
        a, b
    )
\]
```

Suppose my cursor is on `a`. How can I do this with minimal keystrokes?

I'm doing this most often in LaTeX code using VimTeX.

Comment: with vim-sandwich and mappings to mimic vim-surround, `ysib<CR>>>`  https://asciinema.org/a/mOaw3neM6eok1wNBgqGBvlI4q

Comment: Tell us how you would do it so we can tell you how to improve it if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

With https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround, that's `cSbb`/`cS((`.

Manually, I'd go for `vibc<enter><esc>[p==`.

---

Whatever solution you like, you can create a mapping for it:

```
" ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim
nnoremap <buffer> …keys… …solution here…
" adjust b:undo_ftplugin to `execute "silent! nunmap <buffer> …keys…"`
```